# Add custom attributes like serial number to order_item and quote_item

Tags: php, magento

I want to add a custom attribute to magento `order_item` and `quote_item` and a field in the order form for my serial number attribute and other custom attributes.

I'm selling Tablets offline but I am using Magento backend for managing all inventory and customer information along with orders, the tablets are given on subscription bases so there is no shipping as the customer would be at store during purchase.

I want to add custom attribute which are unique to the customer and tablet.

I could create an attribute for the customer but what if they order more than one tablets which means logically the only way is to place those attributes in the order item.

I seriously don't know how to go about.

I hope someone can point me to extended magento sales module and add my custom attribute to `order_item` and also show in magento order form.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to add/change this two tables:

```
- sales_flat_order_item
- sales_flat_quote_item
```

just add fields and name it as you wish (that will be your new attributes)

file you need to edit for your new attribute to be visible on order page should be this one:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

and your new attribute:

```
<?php echo $_item->getMyCustomAttribute() ?>
```

If you would like to make that attribute "the proper way" it requires a bit more skill..
Here is an example how you can add custom category attribute, same would be for your problem:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/

Thanks

Comment: Thank you... I think I would have to get creative and do it on my own...I like the inchoo resource you gave me...would report my progress on this modification

Comment: @Vedean: if customer order more then 1 qty. then their serial nunber would be different. So how can it possible using "- sales_flat_order_item" to add different serial number

Answer (score 0):

I would ask some of the more popular extension providers for a custom quote. AheadWorks comes to my mind quickly... I say visit the Magento Connect store and browse through highly rated extensions and you'll see there are a small number of companies doing lots of successful work.

They will be able to "more properly" handle, store, track, and communicate your desired data through the entire system.

Once I better quantify a similar situation I would like to program, I will seek the help of experienced module builders. The Zend MVC is a miserable bowl of spaghetti once you start trying to code in it! :D